# What's behind the 'joins' method of Active Record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join

Is there a difference between the syntaxes

```
"Game.joins(:round).where('rounds.league_id = 1')"
```

and

```
"Game.joins(:round).where(:rounds => {:league_id => 1})"
```

The first one produces the query:

```
Game Load (7.5ms) 
SELECT "games".* 
FROM "games" INNER JOIN "rounds" ON "rounds"."id" = "games"."round_id" 
WHERE (rounds.league_id = 1)
```

whereas the second produces the longer one:

```
SQL (1.7ms) 
    SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
    FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
    ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
    WHERE a.attrelid = '"rounds"'::regclass
    AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
    ORDER BY a.attnum

Game Load (8.8ms) 
    SELECT "games".* 
    FROM "games" 
    INNER JOIN "rounds" ON "rounds"."id" = "games"."round_id" 
    WHERE "rounds"."league_id" = 1
```

Thanks in advance to everybody, I've just joined the community and this is my first question

Answer (score 4):

In the second log output, what you're seeing is not a longer query but instead ActiveRecord inspecting the schema so it can do the magic that it does. This reflection happens very frequently in development so that any changes to the schema are automatically picked up without having to worry about restarting your processes (be it a console or web server).

If you look at the lines that start with `Game Load`, this is where the the query you're interested in happens and they are nearly identical.